# Function displaying wrong character code value

Tags: java, c#

**Background to my problem**

Hi, I am just attempting to complete an exercise on project Euler which states that I must read all names from a ".txt" file and add all the character codes for each character within that string etc. As I was doing the exercises I realized that the wrong character codes is being displayed.

**This is the full details for my problem from project Euler**

> Using names.txt (right click and 'Save Link/Target As...'), a 46K text
> file containing over five-thousand first names, begin by sorting it
> into alphabetical order. Then working out the alphabetical value for
> each name, multiply this value by its alphabetical position in the
> list to obtain a name score.
>
> For example, when the list is sorted into alphabetical order, COLIN,
> which is worth 3 + 15 + 12 + 9 + 14 = 53, is the 938th name in the
> list. So, COLIN would obtain a score of 938 × 53 = 49714.
>
> What is the total of all the name scores in the file?

**My Question**

why is my code displaying the value "67" for the character "C" when the actual character code value for "C" is 3? . Thanks in advance.

```
private static int NameValue(string name)
{
    string StrimName = name.Substring(1, name.Length-2); // name  --->  COLIN            
    Console.WriteLine(StrimName[0] + 0); // should print 3 because character code for "C" Is 3 but result is 67...
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It prints a number from an ASCII table: http://www.asciitable.com/

You should replace it with:

```
Console.WriteLine((StrimName[0]-64) + 0);
```

to receive what you want. It turns out you want to count 'A' as one, and its number in ASCII table is 65, therefrom I subtract 64.

Answer (score 0):

Every character has a number in the ascii code, 
The ascii-code dor 'C' is 67, This is why you see 67.

[You can see here a table for ascii code](http://www.ascii-code.com/)